# Extracting data from SAS data set based on values with different length

Tags: automation, sas, sas-macro

I am looking to automate a process which has a sales dataset and a specific column named SALES CODE which is of 5 letters.
Based on the input given by the user I would like to filter the data but the problem is the user can give multiple sales codes and sometimes the length of codes could be 5,4,3,2 or 1 based on the condition. How will I filter out the required rows based on the above condition?

```
SALESCODE area value units rep
A10AA            KR     100 10     Jay
B10AQ            TN     120 12     Jrn 
C10AH            KR     200 10     Jay
T11TA             TR     180 10     Jay
```

Say if I give the input as `A10AA, B10A, T11` I should be able to

Get the sales data with codes `A10AA, B10AQ, T11TA.` kindly help.

Comment: What have you tried ? What errors did you get ? Did you try using the input as the basis of a statement using the prefix in operator (`IN:`) ? From Docs on "SAS Operators in Expressions", *Note:   You can add a colon (:) modifier to any of the operators to compare only a specified prefix of a character string. See Character Comparisons for details.* How about as the basis of a `prxmatch` pattern where the inputs commas are changed to regex alternation operator `|` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN operator.  Since you want to match values that start with the specified value use the `:` modifier.  Since your values are character values make sure to include quotes.

```
proc print data=sales_data ;
  where salescode in: ("A10AA" "B10A" "T11");
run;
```

If you want you can use commas between the values in the list, but I find it easier to type spaces instead.